# XML Schema Constraint

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML schema that contains the following line.

```
<Customer Customer_Id = "c5" Age = "24" Years_Of_Membership = "26">
```

Is it possible for me to make a constraint that the value of Years_Of_Membership must be less than the value of Age?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify these kind of constraints with XSD 1.0.

It should be possible in XSD 1.1 using 'assertions':

```
<xs:element name="Customer">
  <xs:complexType>
    . . .
    <xs:assert test="@Years_Of_Membership lt @Age" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

(I say 'should' because I don't have an XSD 1.1 processor to test it).

It might be possible with other schema technologies like Schematron.